# Using cloud9-ide on a network

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I've got the cloud9 IDE up and running on my ubuntu box with the latest code from github today, and node.js 0.6.17.  It seems that I can view it fine on localhost:3131 or 127.0.0.1:3131, but if I try to view it with the machine's actual IP address, either from a different machine or even on the same machine, I get a "not found" error.  Is there any way to get this to work across a network?

(I read that [there is a "-l" command-line argument](http://gratdevel.blogspot.com/2011/11/setting-up-cloud9-on-ubuntu-1110.html) that would let you do this, but for now it doesn't seem to have an effect.  Was this feature removed?  When and why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-l` command indeed has been removed, but only temporary. You can workaround this by patching `configs\default.js`. There are some references to localhost there. Probably changing all instances of localhost into `0.0.0.0` would let the app listen on any host.

edit: Has been fixed